# A workaround for a problem with s.lstrip()

Tags: python-3.x, strip

I am reading an xml file that contains lines of the type:

```
<PLAYER_NAME>Andrew Tell</PLAYER_NAME>
```

I want to extract all the names from the file and I have tried:

```
name = (line.strip()
        .lstrip('<PLAYER_NAME>')
        .rstrip('</PLAYER_NAME>'))
```

and

```
name = line.strip()
name = name.lstrip('<PLAYER_NAME>')
name = name.rstrip('</PLAYER_NAME>')
```

These work for some names but if a name starts with any of:
 A,E,L,M,N,R,Y (and possibly some others) then that character is also stripped as well so in the above example I get 'ndrew Tell' but William Tell is fine.  I have not tested the full alphabet but I do know that names that start with any of: B,C,D,H,I,J,S,T,W are all extracted correctly

I have had to resort to the ugly:

```
namebits = line.split('>',1)
name = namebits[-1].split('<')[0]
```

This seems to work for all names.

I this a known problem with s.lstrip or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Your current attempt is not going into the right direction at all. Use an XML parser - for example [minidom](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/xml.dom.minidom.html)

Comment: First see @Tomalak 's comment. Also for the behavior you're seeing. The argument of `strip` is not a string to b stripped, but characters.  I.e. you can think of it as list of characters which are all individually subject to stripping. Also see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip).

Comment: To parse XML, use a proper XML parser.

Answer (score 3):

Use an XML parser for XML. Every other approach is broken.

Luckily an XML parser is built into Python and using it is easy. It's most probably easier than your current code.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('your_file.xml')

player_name = tree.find('.//PLAYER_NAME')    
print(player_name.text)
```

Read file, [search element](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#elementtree-xpath), get text. No awkward string manipulation required. Assuming this XML file:

```xml
<PLAYER>
    <PLAYER_NAME>Andrew Tell</PLAYER_NAME>
</PLAYER>
```

the output is unsurprising:

```
Andrew Tell
```

Comment: You should really post an answer immediately, and spare the comments (and heartache). Correcting every wrong person on the internet is hard!

Comment: There is no heartache. Not commenting on/pointing out bad solutions misses the point of this site. Some stuff simply is not up for debate.

Comment: I like your resolution. If you feel it is right and are up for it then I salute you.

Comment: Well, it's good enough for me if at least one more person considers an XML parser before trying any other paths.

Comment: As you may tell I am new to Python.  The xml file I am reading has multiple lines of the type < POSITION>a number< /POSITION> followed by multiple lines some of which are the player name lines referred to in the question.  There are an arbitrary number of player name lines.  I want to create a list of tuples (position,name) for each name.

Comment: Try not to think of XML as "lines", that's not useful in the context. There is a hierarchy of elements - a tree. What you want is easily possible, but it depends on the exact structure of the XML document. I suggest you first familiarize yourself with the tree structure (opening the XML file in Google Chrome gives you a nice interactive tree), so you know how the elements are arranged. Then you figure out an angle of attack, e.g. *"for every `<POSITION>`, I need to go over all `<PLAYER_NAME>` and store them in a list*", and then you can start writing your loops. Read about `.findall()`.

Comment: If you get stuck along the way and can't find any helpful examples, you'll be in a good position to write another, more specific question - include a meaningful snippet of your XML, your code so far, your desired output for the XML snippet.